# how to install third party app in my existing Django project?

Tags: python, django, django-geoposition

I'm trying to install django-geoposition app in my existing project but it's not working why?

i follow this documentation of django-geoposition

https://django-geoposition.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#settings

I installed using pip.

```
pip install django-geoposition
```

my installed_apps in settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'images',
    'projects',
    'firms',
    'manufacturers',
    "geoposition",
]
```

when I try to run the project I got this error.

```
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '<frozen importlib._bootstrap>'
```

I think my Django project unable to find this app. what's the problem.

Comment: Did you activate environment before running `pip install` command?

Comment: @hardik24 no how to activate it.